# Accept e-mail calendar requests?

Tags: email, calendar

Is there a way (app, configuration, etc) that will allow me to accept e-mail calendar requests sent to a POP3 account?  The request could be iCal or could originate from Exchange or Outlook.  Once accepted, I would like them to be added to my calendar.

Comment: Minor clarification: The original question was spurred by the Mail application. When I forward calendar requests from work to my phone's e-mail, I can't accept them and they don't get added to my calendar.  However, if I forward an exchange calendar event to my gmail, I don't get an option to add it, either

Comment: What version of Android are you using and what phone? Also, if you have mail app connected to your work email you shouldn't need to forward anything. Just open the app and accept the apt. If you do not have mail connected to your work email and you will not be able to get it connected, then you should sync your phone using sync software, like from HTC or use the app from google that syncs Outlook and Google calendar.

Comment: Froyo (2.2); This includes invitations (such as iCal) sent from other users whether to to my Android GMail or email apps. In my case, it isn't a matter of connecting to work e-mail.

Comment: I am going to update my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, support for this is native in Android.

I have an Exchange account added to my phone (Settings > Accounts & Sync > Add account). Once I snyc'd email and calendar I was able to receive meeting requests through the Mail application, accept them, and then see them show up in my calendar with a different color. The way Google handles Exchange is really sweet.

Update:

So I played around a bit and here is what I found. From the gmail app on the phone you cannot accept appts. But, not sure how it works with iCal and such, I just sent myself a meeting notice from my Exchange Outlook calendar to my gmail account. I signed into Gmail from my computer, got the invite, I clicked yes I am attending, and it now shows on my calendar.

So from the gamil app it appears we cannot accept invites but from a computer we can. :(

Comment: I know this feature is in Android 2.2 Froyo. I'm not sure if this worked in 2.1 or earlier not?

Comment: Yup exists with 2.1 too. I had my phone setup the exact same way with the same feature set on 2.1. Mind you I have an Evo and it is conceivable there was a difference in which version of ActiveSync carriers used for their phone, but I think this is supposed to be set by the Android version. But I say this because in our testing at work we noticed slight differences across phones.

Comment: The context of this question is not _receiving_ through an Exchange account.

Comment: Additional observations. Since original posting, I've received a couple of calendar requests the Mail app that I was able to accept. It appeared to work. I expected to have an "accept" option on the mail message. Instead, I had to open the file attachment before I was offered the option to add it to a calendar. However, I've also had both forwarded Exchange calendar requests and iCal attachments that were not possible to accept. Looks like I have a little more research to do, but the basic matter is resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: Huh so it seems support is flaky then? Good find on opening the attachment! I'll keep my eye open for that next time I get an apt sent to my gmail account.

Answer (score -2):

From giztech.in [How to Accept or Reject Events with Exchange Email in Galaxy S or any Android mobile?](http://giztech.in/index.php/2010/12/10/accepetreject-events-with-exchange-email-in-galaxy-s-or-any-android-mobile/)

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score -2):

It's a known problem in Android system.
You should use a third party app. 
I know (and recommend ןא!) the 'ics 2 android' application. You can download it from google market:
[ics 2 android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdac.icsparser)